# Displaying fetched data from API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I make the data I got from the API display on the page, I can see that it works when I log it to the console but it doesn't show up on the page.

Code:

```
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const GetTodos = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("api/orders");
        console.log(data);
        setTodos(data);
        console.log(todos);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    GetTodos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      {todos?.map((todo) => (
        <p key={todo.ID}>{todo.ID}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Console screenshot:

[image]

Comment: could you put the log of `todos` in the question?

Comment: the log before i setTodos to the data fetched works

Comment: It is normal that the log after `setTodos(data)` do not work, because your `useEffect` runs once. Make a log before your useEffect and see what you get. And please put the response you get in the question.

Comment: the log works but the <p> doesn't show up

Comment: If you show us what is in the array it will be helpful.

Comment: i have added it

Comment: I added an answer below, copy and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem is your data returns an Array of Arrays.
Because your data has just one array nested inside, we can just use it as the data hook, something like this:

```
setTodos(data[0]);
```

to understand, here is an example [image]

Comment: thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

You could do as below, calling `setTodos(data[0])` in your `try-catch`, as your API seems to be returning an array with the data you want at position `0`.

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const GetTodos = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("api/orders");
        console.log(data);
        setTodos(data[0]);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    GetTodos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      {todos && todos.map((todo) => (
        <p key={todo.ID}>{todo.ID}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: Glad that it worked out !